# Trying to verify a hashed password from database with password from login form

Tags: php, mysql, database, password-encryption

I am making a registration and login form, which asks for the user's email and password. In my registration file I hashed the password provided by the user, and stored it in the database, with the function `password_hash`. In my login form I tried to verify the password provided by the user with the stored hashed password in the database, but it fails. I used the `password_verify` function. Here is a snippet of the registration code:

## Registration file snippet

```
if(!isset($error)){
    
    //hash the password
    $hashedpassword = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    echo $hashedpassword;
    
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (mail, password, province) VALUES (:mail, :password, :province)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        //Bind variables
        $stmt->bindValue(':mail', $mail);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password', $hashedpassword); 
        $stmt->bindValue(':province', $province);

        //Execute the statement and insert the new account.
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        //If the signup process is successful.
        if($result){
            echo $hashedpassword;
            exit;
        }
    
     } 
     catch(PDOException $e) {
     $error[] = $e->getMessage();
     }
}
```

#### Hashed passwords in database

For these passwords I get the following hashed passwords, which are stored in the database:

football:
`$2y$10$q0Y8Mfdl75Dt8op7WaqQM.t5y4LMO6gfYwmbycL1xRMiUUQu8dtWm$2y$10$q0Y8Mfdl75Dt8op7WaqQM.t5y4LMO6gfYwmbycL1xRMiUUQu8dtWm`

cricket:
`$2y$10$Pyoz1XC0skRjHLjxHdrYYeYplY98w4uOp23QpZb/VNN0y41/6YPJC$2y$10$Pyoz1XC0skRjHLjxHdrYYeYplY98w4uOp23QpZb/VNN0y41/6YPJC`

The type for the password row is `varchar(255)` and the collation is `utf8mb4_general_ci` The passwords are stored like this:
`$2y$10$q0Y8Mfdl75Dt8op7WaqQM.t5y4LMO6gfYwmbycL1xRM...`
`$2y$10$Pyoz1XC0skRjHLjxHdrYYeYplY98w4uOp23QpZb/VNN...`

When I hover over the passwords it says 'Original length 60'.

## Login file snippet

This is a snippet of my login file code:

```
$mail = htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['mail'], ENT_QUOTES);

if(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) and !empty($_POST['mail'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT mail, password FROM users WHERE mail = :mail');
$stmt->execute(array(':mail' => $mail));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!empty($row['mail'])){
$error[] = 'Email provided is good.';
}

$password = $_POST['password'];
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT password FROM users WHERE password = :password');
$stmt->execute(array(':password' => $password));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$checkpass = $row['password'];
echo $checkpass;
if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
    $error[] = 'Password provided is good.'; 
}
```

Checking whether the email can be found in the database works fine, as it gives me the error message (which I need to change to a normal message).
But I can't get the password verification working. I tried to see what the code pulls out the database with `$checkpass = $row['password'];` and
`echo $checkpass;`
But it doesn't return anything (maybe because it only returns a 0 or 1 value?).
Maybe it has to do something with the way I try to select the hashed password out of the database?  Or the way I insert them in the database, or the MySQL table options? It may be a simple fix but I tried many different things and I couldn't get it to work.. Hope you guys can help!

Comment: You can't query with the literal input password for the database-stored *hashed* password. You should rename the column to something more telling.

Answer (score 3):

The second query seems to be useless since in the first query you already select the mail and password fields. So you should just need to execute the first query, check if the user is valid and then check the password with the `password_verify` method.

Your second query fails (probably) because in the condition you pass the cleartext but in the DB there is the hashed password so you will never find anything. To check print the second query before the execution.

Comment: Okay, can I encrypt the cleartext with the 'password_hash', or does it always generate random encryptions even for the same passwords? Because if that's true I can't check if the hashed input password is the same as the hashed password stored in the database, because they would differ because of the way same passwords get encrypted randomly

Comment: No, you cannot and you don't need it since `password_hash` generate a different hash every time. The logic is to use `password_hash` to generate the hashed password and then to use `password_verify` to check. This is because the output of `password_hash` had all the informations that are needed by `password_verify` to check the password you entered, also if they are always random generated

Comment: @MotambeMarkumbo - Password hashed cannot be verified with SQL because of the salt, one has to load the hash and do the verification in code.

Answer (score -1):

Before executing query for password check in login you should create hashed password for the input password and that hashed password need to be compared

Comment: Sorry, I may not fully understand your answer, but do you mean that I must first encrypt the password given by the user in the login form, so it can correctly match with the password in the database? That actually seems like a reasonable solution if its true. EDIT: But doesn't a password encrypt randomly even if you fill in the same password? Or does the password 'football' encrypt the same way everytime?

Comment: The password 'football' encrypt the same way everytime, as password_hash() creates a new password hash using a strong one-way hashing algorithm.That means we can not decrypt the password, only way to match the password is by encrypting password with same algorithm and comparing against stored password.

Comment: Because of salting, password_hash() produces a different hash every time you hash a password, so they are not comparable.